# Echoing a variable comes out with lots of white space

Tags: html, variables

I'm having trouble when I get variables from WP function come out very long.    How do I trim that down?  trim and substr do not see the spaces before or after.   Why is it so long?

```php
<?php  $image_alt = trim(get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)); ?>
            <?php echo $image_alt;?>
```

when I view the source it looks like this:

```
"

                        HIPAA compliant Times-2 X2 Rotating Shelving Rotating Cabinet Starter and Add-on       "
```

Comment: I see you've a lot of opening and closing tags with lots of spaces and tabs inbetween, are you sure those aren't what you're seeing? This doesn't look like a WP problem but a general PHP issue

Comment: FWIW `the_post_thumbnail()` outputs the alt text automatically. You should rarely need to manually get the text with `get_post_meta()`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Tom J Nowell's comment, any whitespace **after** `?>` and **before** `<?php` will get output, so if you are adding an alt tag you need to make there there's no extra white space outside the `<?php ?>`. Here's an example, and I've simplified your code a bit as you can do that in one command:

```
<img src="..." alt="<?php echo trim(get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)); ?>">
```

If you need more help it's useful to put the whole bit of code you're using in your question